# Fade background color on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-color, fade

I'm trying to do something pretty standard: fading a background color on the click of a separate div. www.jamesjano.com

clicking the white circles is supposed to fade the black bg to white. i've tried using the animate but it isn't working (although it is working with the opacity of the content box).... I've tried everything and can't figure this out. Also what's weird is that it works locally but not when it's live. Any and all help would be appreciated. here's the code i'm using:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#logo, #sec_log").click(function() { 
    $(".animate").stop().animate({"backgroundColor":"#ffffff"}, 800); },function() { 
    $(".animate").stop().animate({"backgroundColor":"#ffffff"}, 800); 

    }); 
});   

 </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Default jQuery package does not have `background-color` animation capability. You have to use [Color Animation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) from jQuery UI. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zHv2e/) is a working example.

Comment: I copied that same code and still no dice. I feel like i might not be calling out to the right script?

Comment: Copying same code will not fix your problem. Before that you have to include jQuery UI libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Read Emre's answer to learn how to animate the `background-color` attribute.  CSS did not support the `opacity` attribute for background-colors until CSS3.